# Android open GL ES issue with samsung s8

Tags: android, opengl-es, samsung-mobile, fragment-shader

I created an Android lib that includes image processing via OpenGL ES.
the lib works fine on Android devices, but only on Samsung S8 it crashes while running - the opengl shaders compile, but the opengl program does not link, and the error log is empty.
The crash comes from one of my openGLES filters in the fragment Shader.

The crash is in the "if" Line:

```
    "if (gradientMagnitude >= firstSampledGradientMagnitude && gradientMagnitude >= secondSampledGradientMagnitude)"
    "{"
     ...
    "}"
```

it also crashes if i try:

```
   "if (gradientMagnitude >= firstSampledGradientMagnitude)"
   "{"
   "if (gradientMagnitude >= secondSampledGradientMagnitude)"
   "{"
   ...
   "}"
   "}"
```

however it works if i only do one comparison:

```
"if (gradientMagnitude >= firstSampledGradientMagnitude)"
"{"
...
"}"
```

OR

```
"if (gradientMagnitude >= secondSampledGradientMagnitude)"
"{"
...
"}"
```

In the end I fixed the crash with this solution:

```
"float sampledGradientMagnitudeMax = max(firstSampledGradientMagnitude,secondSampledGradientMagnitude);"
"if (gradientMagnitude >= sampledGradientMagnitudeMax)"
"{"
...
"}"
```

My question is, why does it crash in the first code?

Comment: It's possible that with the first line in place, you're exceeding some instruction count (instruction limits can be rather under-specced), but more likely is it's due to a compiler bug. You could always try and contact Samsung, but there's a 90% chance their driver team already fixed the bug and it's just a matter of time before the fix is rolled out across the product line, so it might be wasted effort to do so.